# Open Source CMS in java for web content managment with source code to develop in eclipse for custom changes

Tags: java, jsp, content-management-system, alfresco, dotcms

I am looking for open source CMS in Java for content management system.

I have started using `Alfresco` and `dotCMS` but getting error in installing n configuring on window.

I followed all step given in their own website but stuck at some point.

please provide a step to installation n configuration

My concern is that if I succeed in installing then also this 2 CMS provide the source code also for developing customize CMS ?

Other thing is their any way to develop CMS in core java also using JSP/SERVLET also ?

Provide me any solution who ever develop customize CMS in java either in open CMS or in  core java(jsp/servlet).

Comment: can you please provide specific error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, dotCMS provides the features that you are looking for like using servlets to build your own stuff on top of their API's. Have you tried their dotcms_2.3.1.exe windows installer? It includes the database stuff and everything and should work. If it doens't you can ask questions on their google group page (https://groups.google.com/group/dotcms) and most likely there will be somebody that can help you out.